# 3rd party UI libraries (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have difficulty defining 3rd **UI** party packages for my Angular app correctly (I joined an existing project).

Please, be understanding. I've read about 3rd party libraries but I still have a problem and want to define it correctly.

For example:
ngx-sharedbuttons - I use it to display social buttons. Is that UI 3rd party package?

What about

- rxjs -> it's not, I believe, but maybe I misunderstood the topic
- ng-recaptcha
- file-system
- sitemap-generator
- outdated-browser-rework
- @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
- @angular/forms
- @nguniversal/express-engine

if anyone could explain in own words... I will be really grateful

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.  But, yes, I would consider `ngx-sharedbuttons` a 3rd party library since it is not part of Angular.  I would not consider `rxjs` a third party library since it is required to run Angular and is installed as part of the process of creating a new project.

Comment: @JeffryHouser your answer helped a lot. So 3rd party = libraries that are not part of Angular an are not required, something like that? And do you know how to define UI libraries? E.g recaptcha is a UI 3rd party package, am I right?

Comment: You can create UI Libraries with the Angular CLI: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries .  If you want to share them w/ other people, you'll want to publish them to the npm repository (Instructions in that guide)